# How to apply polynominal function in Neural Network?

Tags: neural-network, regression

I already know how to work the "simple formula" in Neural Network as follow:

```
f = as.formula(paste("logK ~",paste(n[!n %in% "logK"], collapse = " + ")))
```

But I have a problem with how to apply the polynominal model into the neural network.

```
n = names(dataset)
f = as.formula(paste("logK ~.-Co-Ru +I(Cr ^ 3)+I(Mo ^ 3)+I(Re ^ 3)+I(Ti ^ 3) +I(Temp ^ 3)+I(Re ^5 )+I(Temp ^ 5)+I(Cr ^ 7)+I(Re ^ 7)+I(Re ^ 9)", paste(n[!n %in% "logK"])))
nn = neuralnet(f, data = trainset, hidden = 10, act.fct = "tanh")
```

Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE): :1:121: unexpected symbol
1: logK ~.-Co-Ru +I(Cr ^ 3)+I(Mo ^ 3)+I(Re ^ 3)+I(Ti ^ 3) +I(Temp ^ 3)+I(Re ^5 )+I(Temp ^ 5)+I(Cr ^ 7)+I(Re ^ 7)+I(Re ^ 9) Al
^
Traceback:

1. as.formula(paste("logK ~.-Co-Ru +I(Cr ^ 3)+I(Mo ^ 3)+I(Re ^ 3)+I(Ti ^ 3) +I(Temp ^ 3)+I(Re ^5 )+I(Temp ^ 5)+I(Cr ^ 7)+I(Re ^ 7)+I(Re ^ 9)",
   .     paste(n[!n %in% "logK"])))
2. formula(object, env = baseenv())
3. formula.character(object, env = baseenv())
4. formula(eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]]))
5. eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]])
6. parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)